# pandas how to count comma only outside of quotation then apply split and explode function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have list in my dataframe like this `['https://c1.zzounds.com/media/productmedia/fit,600by600/quality,85/GIGBAR_MOVE_ON_TRIPOD_812129-0eddea01276623f9a03cbfdd86eb3bd1.jpg', 'https://c1.zzounds.com/media/productmedia/fit,600by600/quality,85/CVT_GIGBARMOVEWH-d84ad5c983c1c28ed662151405c22145.jpg']`. In this list I have two url which seperated by comma but the problem it's exploding multiple row because it's also counting comma inside of `''` quotion.

here is my dataframe:

```
product_title   variatons_color         url
T-shirt          ['yellow','ornage']   ['https://c1.zzounds.com/media/productmedia/fit,600by600/quality,85/GIGBAR_MOVE_ON_TRIPOD_812129-0eddea01276623f9a03cbfdd86eb3bd1.jpg', 'https://c1.zzounds.com/media/productmedia/fit,600by600/quality,85/CVT_GIGBARMOVEWH-d84ad5c983c1c28ed662151405c22145.jpg']
```

my expected dataframe will be look like this:

```
    product_title   variatons_color         url
    T-shirt          yellow                https://c1.zzounds.com/media/productmedia/fit,600by600/quality,85/GIGBAR_MOVE_ON_TRIPOD_812129-0eddea01276623f9a03cbfdd86eb3bd1.jpg
    T-shirt          orange                https://c1.zzounds.com/media/productmedia/fit,600by600/quality,85/CVT_GIGBARMOVEWH-d84ad5c983c1c28ed662151405c22145.jpg
```

Comment: A simple explode should work as long as URLs are encoded as list elements?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your dataframe contains strings that look like arrays. You can use `ast.literal_eval` to convert them to arrays:

```py
import ast

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "product_title": "T-shirt",
    "variatons_color": "['yellow','orange']",
    "url": "['https://c1.zzounds.com/media/productmedia/fit,600by600/quality,85/GIGBAR_MOVE_ON_TRIPOD_812129-0eddea01276623f9a03cbfdd86eb3bd1.jpg', 'https://c1.zzounds.com/media/productmedia/fit,600by600/quality,85/CVT_GIGBARMOVEWH-d84ad5c983c1c28ed662151405c22145.jpg']"
}, index=[0])

for col in ["variatons_color", "url"]:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(ast.literal_eval)
df.explode(["variatons_color", "url"])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check your answer and let you know.

Comment: getting this error ValueError: malformed node or string: nan

Answer (score 1):

As long as your data is correctly encoded as list (url) a simple explode should do the job

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'product_title': ['T-Shirt'],
 'variatons_color':[['yellow','ornage']],
 'url' : [['https://c1.zzounds.com/media/productmedia/fit,600by600/quality,85/GIGBAR_MOVE_ON_TRIPOD_812129-0eddea01276623f9a03cbfdd86eb3bd1.jpg', 'https://c1.zzounds.com/media/productmedia/fit,600by600/quality,85/CVT_GIGBARMOVEWH-d84ad5c983c1c28ed662151405c22145.jpg']]})

>>> df.explode('url')

product_title   variatons_color url
0   T-Shirt [yellow, ornage]    https://c1.zzounds.com/media/productmedia/fit,...
0   T-Shirt [yellow, ornage]    https://c1.zzounds.com/media/productmedia/fit,...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check your answer and let you know

Comment: Danail I also need to explode my `variation_color `. Please see my expected dataframe

Comment: Danail Petrov I am reading data from csv and not understanding why it's not working in my actual dataframe